# compiler not recognizing vector as class member

Tags: c++, vector

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INLhi.png)I am trying out some STL programs. I have declared a vector in main and tried to run the program it is working but if i declare the same(vector) inside the class then am getting a compilation error. I think compiler is not recognizing vector(declared inside the class).

I have tried with std:: also still same error. I am using netbeans IDE and cigwin compiler.

please find the code below

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

/*
 * 
*/

class vectorcl 
{
   vector<int> v(10);
   int i;
public:
   vectorcl();
   void add_vector();
   void dis_vector();

};

vectorcl :: vectorcl()
{
    for(i =0;i<10 ;i++)
    {
       v[i] = 0;
    }
}

void vectorcl :: dis_vector()
{     
   cout<< " The vale is : \n";
   for(i =0;i<10 ;i++)
   {
       cout << "\t " <<v[i];
   }
}

void vectorcl :: add_vector()
{
   for (i =0 ; i<10; i++)
   {
       v[i] = i+1;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
//    vector<int> vp(10);
//    for(int j =0;j<10 ;j++)
//    {
//        cout << " " << vp[j];
//    }

   vectorcl v1;
   v1.dis_vector();
   v1.add_vector();
   v1.dis_vector();
   return 0;
}
```

Please help me in this, my question is why my compiler is not recognizing vector declared inside a class.

error  : expected identifier before numeric constant
expected ',' or '...'before numeric constant

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INLhi.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual error messages, complete, in full and unedited.

Comment: This probably shouldn't have java as a tag.

Comment: A hint about your problem though: You need to read about *constructor member initializer lists*.

Comment: Lastly an unrelated tip: Don't use member variables for things that should be local variables. The member variable `i` should really be a local variable in the functions you use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `vector<int> v(10);` as member variable. The solution is to replace it by  `vector<int> v;` and add this alter the constructor like this:

```
vectorcl::vectorcl():
    v(std::vector<int>(10,0/* This 0 is instead of the for-loop*/)){
}
```

Or another option is to declare it as :

```
std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>(10);
```

P.S. there is no need to declare int i as class member. Just declare it in every function you need.

Comment: You don't need that loop.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes of course. I just leave it as the OP wrote. I am going to edit thanks

Answer (score 1):

From first glance, you are trying to call the constructor in the class prototype: `vector<int> v(10);`. Your constructor for that class will be called in your wrapper class constructor unless you use a member initialization list.

Edit: using member initialization

```
vectorcl :: vectorcl(): v(10)
{
}
```

Comment: The real issue is that the syntax is invalid. This would work: `vector<int> v = vector<int>(10);`

Comment: Are you sure that would actually change anything? That would be invoking v's copy constructor in the same way that `vector<int>(10)` would invoke its constructor. Both are honestly poor design anyways.

Comment: It would change something, because it would work, as opposed to not even compiling. But no, it wouldn't be invoking the constructor at that point. Construction only happens at instantiation.

Comment: Vector items are value-initialized, this loop is redundant

Comment: @Russley Shaw  : Thanks for your honest answer. I am very new to STL, and trying out some vector..hope future my design will be better

Comment: @DhanyaKUMAR.S I recommend Scott Meyers and his collection of C++ books. There is Effective C++, STL, and Modern Effective C++. All three are some of the best C++ resources I have read and I have learned so much from them.

Comment: @juanchopanza : Thanks a lot for your suggestion..Its working with this syntax vector<int> v = vector<int>(10);